# about fixing seed in wrapped C++ code in swig

Tags: c++, swig

I have wrapped a random generator in C++ with swig, (this is an over simplified verion of an stochastic differential Eq. solver) and I am looking for a way to reset the seeding random generators after multiple calling it. It's possible by running again the script but in notebook it need to restart the kernel.

I mean:

```py
for i in range(2)
    print(mymodule.rand_cpp2(1))
```

should give different values.

then I am looking for a command to reset the seed and by calling again

````py
for i in range(2)
    print(mymodule.rand_cpp2(1))```
````

should return the same results (solving SDE with the same random numbers).

I have defind the random generator like the following:

```cpp
std::mt19937 &rng(const bool fix_seed)
{
    if (fix_seed)
    {
        static std::mt19937 instance{2};
        return instance;
    }
    else
    {
        static std::mt19937 instance{std::random_device{}()};
        return instance;
    }
}


double rand_cpp1(unsigned seed)
{
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
    std::normal_distribution<> normal(0, 1);
    return normal(generator);
}

double rand_cpp2(unsigned fix_seed)
{
    std::normal_distribution<> normal(0, 1);
    return normal(rng(fix_seed));
}
```

here `rand_cpp2` gives different values but I need to restart the kernel to get the same chain of random numbers.

`rand_cpp1` gives the same random number unless I change the seed and generating generator is not efficient for each random number.

Do you have any idea?

P.S
reloading the module doesn't work

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import mymodule
```

I have uploaded the full code in case to reproduce the results https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iLGrrg9w1oBuu3ystTPlttAw6E-nSQ1a?usp=sharing.

Comment: `static std::mt19937 instance{2};` will only ever run *once*.

Answer (score 0):

There are different strategies possible. The best possible solution would be to export a class containing the random generator that it is visible from Python so that you can do:

```py
gen = generator(42)  # Create a generator object
gen.rnd()            # Use it...
gen.rnd()
....
```

and then you call this which will give you the same sequence:

```py
gen2 = generator(42)
gen2.rnd()
gen2.rnd()
```

Just create a C++ class:

```
class generator {
  std::default_random_engine engine;
  std::normal_distribution<> normal;
public:
  generator(int seed) : engine(seed), normal(0, 1) {}
  double rand() { return normal(engine); }
};
```

and wrap this in a SWIG interface file.